# How to group groovy tests?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit

I have a few groovy test cases (i.e. classes that extend `GroovyTestCase` (version 1.8.2)). For example

```
class TestCaseA extends GroovyTestCase {void testA1() {...} void testA2() {...}}
class TestCaseB extends GroovyTestCase {void testB1() {...} void testB2() {...}}
```

I would like to group the tests (test methods).
For example,

```
group X: TestCaseA.testA1, TestCaseB.testB1, TestCaseB.testB2,
group Y: TestCaseB.testB2
group Z: TestCaseA.testA1, TestCaseA.testA2
```

In order to implement such grouping I would like to add *annotations*. (I can change the test sources).
For example:

```
class TestCaseA extends GroovyTestCase {

   @TestGroup (TestGroup.X, TestGroup.Z)   
   void testA1() {...}

   @TestGroup (TestGroup.Z)   
   void testA2() {...}
}
```

Now I would like to write a *custom* `JUnit Runner`, which receives the "test groups" (e.g. as a command line argument or environment variable) and runs only the test methods annotated with these groups.

Does it make sense? What are the alternatives? How to implement the *custom* JUnit Runner?

Answer (score 3):

Might not be what you are looking for, but an alternative is to use TestNG which supports groups concept out-of-the box http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups. Should work fine with Groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+TestNG+with+Groovy

I know it is useless for you, if you are stuck with JUnit...

Comment: I agree.  That should work.  I have been playing around with this stuff lately and I know that it will work.